# Which clustering algorithm is the best when number of cluster is unknown but there is no noise?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset with unknown number of clusters and I aim to cluster them. Since, I don't know the number of clusters in advance, I tried to use density-based algorithms especially DBSCAN. The problem that I have with DBSCAN is that how to detect appropriate epsilon. The method suggested in the DBSCAN paper assume there are some noises and when we plot sorted k-dist graph we can detect valley and define the threshold for epsilon. But, my dataset obtained from a controlled environment and there are no noise.

Does anybody have an idea of how to detect epsilon? Or, suggest better clustering algorithm could fit this problem.

Comment: If your environment is controlled, you can sure compute a good epsilon. For geogrsphic data, I like using 10 miles as epsilon, or 100 miles, depending on what I'm looking for, instead of relying on some heuristic to compute a meaningless value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, there is no unsupervised epsilon detection.  From what little you describe, DBSCAN is a very appropriate approach.

Real-world data tend to have a gentle gradient of distances; deciding what distance should be the cut-off is a judgement call requiring knowledge of the paradigm and end-use.   In short, the problem requires knowledge not contained in the raw data.

I suggest that you use a simple stepping approach to converge on the solution you want.  Set epsilon to some simple value that your observation suggests will be appropriate.  If you get too much fragmentation, increase epsilon by a factor of 3; if the clusters are too large, decrease by a factor of 3.  Repeat your runs until you get the desired results.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've already done stepping approach and your factor 3 idea seems interesting